# How does Clojure state work?

Tags: clojure, quil

I know what state is by concept, but I can't understand how it's been implemented in this example:
https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/examples/gen_art/31_oo_circles.clj

I just simply don't see it. State implementation happens on lines **100, 109, and 137**:

98-100:

```
(defn mouse-released []
  (add-circles (state :circles)))
```

109:

`(set-state! :circles circles*)`

135-140:

```
(defn draw []
  (background 255)
  (let [circles* (state :circles)
        circles (swap! circles* update-circles)]
    (doseq [c circles]
      (draw-circle c))))
```

What is happening on those lines?

***set-state!*** is a Quil method, its implementation can be found at https://github.com/quil/quil/wiki/set~state%21

Comment: Are you aware of clojure STM constructs like Atom and Ref?

Comment: in this context "state" is the name of a var (not the most creative name in my opinion, but it gets the point across)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer: it's using an [atom](https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/src/quil/applet.clj#L374) defined in applet.clj

It's a function defined in [core.clj](https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/src/quil/core.clj) on line 17 which extracts state information stored as an atom attached to the metadata on the applet. Set state start by finding the atom that stored the current "state" by calling `(:state (meta (current-applet))` which extracts the metadata (which is a map) form the applet object, then returns the atom stored in the :state key. It then calls `reset!` to put a new value in this atom. 
It gets included by the (:use quil.core) in the `ns` declaration.

Comment: I know set-state is coming from Quil but my question is what does exactly setting the state means/do?